# Count Distinct Query to a Date Field by Using Criteria API

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria-api

I am trying to count distinct query to a date field by using criteria api. Here is what I have done;

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Long> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Long.class);
Root<?> queryRoot = criteriaQuery.from(MyClass.class);

Expression dateExpression = queryRoot.get("myDate");

Expression dayExpression = criteriaBuilder.function("day", Integer.class, dateExpression);
Expression monthExpression = criteriaBuilder.function("month", Integer.class, dateExpression);
Expression dayExpression = criteriaBuilder.function("year", Integer.class, dateExpression);

criteriaQuery.select((Selection) criteriaBuilder.countDistinct(criteriaBuilder.concat(dayExpression, criteriaBuilder.concat(monthExpression, yearExpression))));

entityManager.executeCriteria(criteriaQuery, 0, 1);
```

I tried to concat because `countDistinct` function only gets one expression.

When I execute this I get;

```
javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting CLOSE, found '(' near line 1, column 31 [select count(distinct function('day', generatedAlias0.manufacturedDate) || function('month', generatedAlias0.manufacturedDate) || function('year', generatedAlias0.manufacturedDate)) from com.myCompany.entity.MyClass as generatedAlias0]
```

According to my googling, criteria query does not support function in count and using native query advised. But I need to do it with criteria api or hibernate because I write this into our framework and it has to run correctly for all entities.

I use PosgreSQL 9.5 and Hibernate 5.0.7 which is coming with Wildfly 10.0.

How can I make this run with Hibernate or Criteria Api.

Great thanks for any help and advise.

Comment: please refer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354704/select-distinct-entities-by-specific-column

Comment: @vishalgajera thanks for advise but how this will help to solve my problem. I couldn't understand.

Comment: Why do you need to use function to parse the date and then concat it to do the count distinct ?

Comment: Because I will group them according to day, month and year. Also, I want to show the number of values to user.